# Iterate over dataframe

Tags: pandas

Bit of a newb question but here goes...

I have a dataframe of timeseries values as follows.

```
Index                  Value A    Value B
2019-02-05 18:00:00    1.16       6.32
2019-02-05 17:00:00    1.1475     23.7825
2019-02-05 18:00:00    1.16       6.32
2019-02-05 17:00:00    1.1475     23.7825
2019-02-05 16:00:00    0.4125     23.7825
2019-02-05 15:00:00    0.0        31.71
2019-02-05 14:00:00    0.0        23.7825
2019-02-05 13:00:00    1.015      23.7825
2019-02-05 12:00:00    0.24       23.7825
```

For each row in the dataframe I would like to identify the last 24 preceding values and write them to a new dataframe against the original index. The results would look something like this.

```
Index                  Time diff Value A    Value B
2019-02-05 18:00:00     0         1.16       6.32
2019-02-05 18:00:00     -1        1.147      23.7825
2019-02-05 18:00:00     -2        1.16       6.32
2019-02-05 18:00:00     -3        1.147      23.7825
2019-02-05 18:00:00     etc...    etc....    etc....
2019-02-05 18:00:00     -23       1.147      23.7825
```

So in summary for each row in my original dataframe I would end up with 24 rows in the new dataframe with a new column indicating the time lag.

The reason for this operation is to prepare the data for machine learning where the index is our target and the 24 associated historical values are the predictor variables.

At present I am attempting to use something like...

```
for i, row in be_hour.iterrows():
    if <something>:
        df.at[i, 'ifor'] = x
    else:
        df.at[i, 'ifor'] = y
```

But I'm struggling to actually implement this given my lack of experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution I have come up with:

```
import pandas as pd

idx = ['2019-02-05 18:00:00',
       '2019-02-05 17:00:00', 
       '2019-02-05 16:00:00',
       '2019-02-05 15:00:00',
       '2019-02-05 14:00:00',
       '2019-02-05 13:00:00',
       '2019-02-05 12:00:00']

A = [1.16, 1.1475, 1.1475, 0.4125, 0.0, 1.015, 0.24]
B = [6.32, 23.7825, 23.7825, 23.7825, 23.7825, 23.7825, 23.7825]

idx = [pd.Timestamp(t) for t in idx]
idx = pd.Index(idx)
d = {'A': A, 'B': B}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
df = df.set_index(idx)

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in df.index:
    top = i
    bot = top - pd.Timedelta('3 hour')
    result = df.loc[top:bot]
    for j in result.index:
        diff = top - j
        row = {'timestamp': top, 'diff': diff, 'A': df.A[j], 'B': df.B[j]}
        df1 = df1.append(row, ignore_index=True)
df1 = df1.set_index('timestamp')
```

Comment: Many thanks, this works perfectly. Your help is much appreciated.